# TWTRComposer() Application crashes when I try to open Composer

Tags: swift, twitter

I am having an issue with TWTRComposer. I installed TwitterKit using pods followed all other instructions i.e. updated info.Plist , AppDelegate and so on. I am using Swift. When I call the func that handles the code the app crashes here, sample code below. On the line where composer.show(from: self.navigationController!) the error message is Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode=0x1024ff1ac) I have no clue what this means. Any explanation and help is appreciated.

```
  let composer = TWTRComposer()

    composer.setText("just setting up my Twitter Kit")
    composer.setImage(UIImage(named: "twitterkit"))

    // Called from a UIViewController
    composer.show(from: self.navigationController!) { (result) in
        if (result == .done) {
        print("Successfully composed Tweet")
        } else {
        print("Cancelled composing")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an error in console saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" ? Guess? `self.navigationController` is nil, and since you do `self.navigationController!` that's saying: Let's hope it's not nil else it will crash, which is what is happening.

Comment: Okay I did not see that but will run it again and check thanks for the direction.

Comment: Ok yes the navcontroller was nil, so I assigned the class to be navcontrollerdelegate and still getting the msg. Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2018-03-16 07:49:06.858929-0400 Mi Moods[10397:3398413] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Question: Do you have a NavigationController on your app? Because if not, self.navigationController will always be nil. If `self` is a `UIViewController`, why not doing ` composer.show(from: self`){...}`?

Comment: Good morning, Okay originally I did not have a NavController attached to that class than i embedded one with the same result. I have tried the composer.show(from:self){} app still crashes with no logs to show nil object. Funny thing is that the Facebook method works with no issue. I reinstalled the pods for Twitter, will give it another try but still confused why FB works and Twitter does not.

Comment: You put a NavigationController finally? Then, is `self.navigationController` nil?

Comment: Yes, I included the Nav controller and it is Nil, been trying to figure a way to initialize it but not worked yet. Any ideas ? Thanks for your help